# Why do both the types of loops return a zero in the following code?

Tags: c

This program finds the factorial of a number with a non-recursive method,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial(int x);
int main()
{
    int a,fact;

    printf("Enter the number whose factorial is needed\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    fact= factorial(a);

    printf("The factorial of %d is %d",a,fact);
}
```

Now, if I use the for loop with either the counter i increments or decrements both the times the outcome is "The factorial of 5 is 0"

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int f=1,i;

    for(i=x;i>=1;i--)//or one can use the for(i=1;i<=x;i++) loop
    {
        f=f*i;
    }
    return(f);
}
```

and now even the recursive one is returning the factorial as zero

```
   int factorial(int x)
   {
     int f;
     if(x==1)
     return(f);

     else

     f= x*factorial(x-1);
     return(f);
   }
```

Personally, I couldn't find any format error or syntax error, could you?

Comment: did you check for overflow? signed Integer overflow is ***dangerous!!!***

Comment: The code looks all right.

Comment: @SouravGhosh See the paragraph between two code blocks. The input is `5`.

Comment: @iBug that is why it is a comment!!

Comment: Would you kindly provide the _actual_ Minimal, Complete and so forth example? The code you provided evaluates 5! to 120—after the typo corrected, so apparently it is not the code that made you confused.

Comment: @bipll If it weren't your comment I didn't even notice the typo!

Comment: @iBug is it how your nickname contains a Bug? :)

Comment: In your recursive case `f` is uninitialized. This makes it operate on unknown value for the base case.

Comment: I've used it with both the initialized and uninitialized forms

Comment: Put debug print in the loop:

f=f*i;
printf("i = %d, f=%d\n",i,f);

what is the log?

Comment: i = 5   f = 5
i = 4   f = 20
i = 3   f = 60
i = 2   f = 120
i = 1   f = 120

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: f = 120
so what's the issue? :)
change the code this way, what is the output?
int res = 0;
...
res = factorial(a);
printf("res=%d\n",res);

Comment: The onlybug here is not initialized f to 1. But the rest of the code work fine on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

Your function prototype is incorrect: you have misspelt the function name.

This causes your compiler to rely on an *implicit* declaration of the function which causes spurious effects when it encounters the actual definition. (A variable argument list is assumed).

Check your spellings, and crank up the warning level on your compiler: implicit function definitions have been disallowed since C99.

(Also note that the upper limit for an `int` can be as small as +32767. That's only good for 7! and lower. Consider using a larger type such as `unsigned long long` which will be good to at least 21! - and don't forget to validate the input before calling the function.)

Your recursive function is buggy (i) `f` if not initialised on all control paths, (ii) `x == 1` as the stopping condition is vulnerable to an input of `0` called on the top level, (iii) the `else` is redundant luckily for you as only the immediate statement is part of the `else` condition.

As for your getting 0 on large inputs, the behaviour on overfloating an `int` is undefined. Mathematically, a large factorial value ends up being a multiple of a large power of 2. The wraparound behaviour normally experienced when overflowing an `int` is effectively giving you a result modulo a power of 2. Those two effects conspire to give you a zero return value.

Comment: If the compiler supports implicit function declarations (i.e. C89/90 or K&R) a variable argument list is assumed, not a `void` argument list.

Comment: @Peter: Well that I didn't know. I've changed it on your authority. Now just checking if 21! would work - I can never remember the limit.

Comment: Well it still brings a zero!

Comment: The entire world including major books and the online compilers have been telling me to avoid the `void` and you're totally opposite

Comment: @AndrewGates: Avoid the `void`? What do you mean?

Comment: I meant the big people have been advising me to use `int` instead of `void`

Comment: could you check the  recursive one for me too as well?

Comment: @AndrewGates: I've added some commentary on the recursive version -

Comment: @Bathsheba where give me the link please

Answer (score 1):

Beware, integer types have limits, and overflow is undefined behaviour per standard.

Even if you used an implementation that just ignores high order bytes (which is what most common ones do), you will add a 0 bit on the right (in binary) each time you multiply a number with 2. That means that as soon as the factorial will be a multiple of 2<sup>32</sup>, the computed value will contain 32 0 bits => it is 0 on a 32 bit machine.

To compute large factorials, you will need a specialized library like [gmp](https://gmplib.org/), or implement one *by hand*

Answer (score -2):

I dont know why the output is like that but your code is buggy.
The spelling of factorial is incorrect.

```
int factroial(int x);
```

should be

```
int factorial(int x);
```